# Error: Adapter not attached, skipping layout to class while using recyclerview and firebase

Tags: java, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I have tried a lot fixing this, but not able to. it says my adapter is not attached. but when i declare a adapter in onCreate and run, it shows a blank activity for the following code:

**mainactivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    DatabaseReference collegereference;
    private CollegeAdapter collegeAdapter;
    List<College> collegelist = new List<College>(); //lot of functions under this which i didnt put in this question

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler);
        collegereference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("colleges");         
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        collegeAdapter = new CollegeAdapter(MainActivity.this,collegelist);
        //initialised adapter after getting 'adapter not attached, skipping activity'
        //i am not getting this error anymore but when i run, a blank acitvity pops up
        recyclerView.setAdapter(collegeAdapter);
        collegereference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1: dataSnapshot.getChildren())
                {
                    collegelist.add(dataSnapshot1.getValue(College.class));
                }
                recyclerView.setAdapter(collegeAdapter);
                collegeAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "unsuccessful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

    }

}
```

this is my adapter class:

**CollegeAdapter.java**

```
public class CollegeAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CollegeAdapter.CollegeViewHolder>  {

    Context c;
    private List<College> collegelist;

    public CollegeAdapter(Context c, List<College> collegelist)
    {
        LayoutInflater manager = LayoutInflater.from(c);
        this.c = c;
        this.collegelist = collegelist;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public CollegeAdapter.CollegeViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
    {
        return new CollegeViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(c).inflate(R.layout.collegecardview,parent,false));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull CollegeAdapter.CollegeViewHolder holder, int position) 
    {
        holder.collegename.setText(collegelist.get(position).getName());
        holder.rating.setText(collegelist.get(position).getRating());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() 
    {
        return collegelist.size(); //points to null, when there was no adapter initialised in onCreate
    }

    public class CollegeViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder 
    {
        TextView collegename,rating;

        public CollegeViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) 
        {
            super(itemView);
            collegename = itemView.findViewById(R.id.collegename);
            rating = itemView.findViewById(R.id.rating);
        }
    }
}
```

my cardview layout is :

**mainactivity.xml**

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

my cardview activty:
**collegecardview.xml**

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:weightSum="2"
android:orientation="horizontal">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="College Name"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/collegename"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Rating"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="15sp"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/rating"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/collegeimage"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

And now i get this error:

```
04-28 06:27:37.832 15830-15830/? I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
04-28 06:27:37.896 15830-15830/? W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.collegefirebase-2/lib/x86_64
04-28 06:27:37.917 15830-15830/com.example.collegefirebase I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization successful
04-28 06:27:37.940 15830-15830/com.example.collegefirebase W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter androidx.vectordrawable.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
04-28 06:27:38.006 15830-15830/com.example.collegefirebase I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<androidx.core.view.ViewCompat$2>
04-28 06:27:38.006 15830-15830/com.example.collegefirebase I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<androidx.core.view.ViewCompat$2>
04-28 06:27:38.239 15830-15853/com.example.collegefirebase D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
04-28 06:27:38.335 15830-15853/com.example.collegefirebase I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
04-28 06:27:38.339 15830-15853/com.example.collegefirebase W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
04-28 06:27:38.350 15830-15853/com.example.collegefirebase D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0x7fc29c10a6e0: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
04-28 06:27:38.366 15830-15853/com.example.collegefirebase D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x7fc29c10a6e0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 
0x7fc29ca05a80)
04-28 06:27:38.408 15830-15853/com.example.collegefirebase D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x7fc29c10a6e0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x7fc29ca05a80)
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First you are creating the list in a wrong way, and thats why you see lots of functions:

**instead of this:**

```
List<College> collegelist = new List<College>();
```

**do this:**

```
List<College> collegelist = new ArrayList<College>();
```

**And add the `adapter` initialization inside the `onDataChange()` method:**

```
collegereference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1: dataSnapshot.getChildren())
        {
            collegelist.add(dataSnapshot1.getValue(College.class));
        }

        //create adapter here

        collegeAdapter = new CollegeAdapter(MainActivity.this,collegelist);

        //set the adapter

        recyclerView.setAdapter(collegeAdapter);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "unsuccessful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

Comment: when initialised adapter in onDataChange,throws error: adapter not attached.I initialised it again like before, and it just shows a blank activity with following in verbose: **04-28 14:39:00.493 16843-16843/com.example.collegefirebase W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter androidx.vectordrawable.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode)would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable**

Comment: I really don't know maybe it is a problem with your reference, or the class `College`

Comment: You are right, there was a problem in reference. i was using wrong child name. Your suggestion for list declaration was right, but we have to initialise an empty adapter after layout manager for recycler view, else it says adapter not attached. Thanks :) @Hasan

Comment: If the answer solved your issue, make sure to accept so other know. GoodLuck.